# Unable to change page style via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, styles, numbers, undefined

I'm having an issue getting a value from my script make a change on my website. What I'm trying to accomplish, is to allow users to scroll through some elements on my page, going left or right. Keep in mind I'm not very good with JavaScript, so here is what I have so far.

```
window.onload = makeActive;
function makeActive() {
var showCase = document.getElementById("showcase");
var slides = showCase.getElementsByTagName("div");
var mouseDown = false;
if(window.addEventListener) {
    showCase.addEventListener('mousedown',startDrag,false);
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',drag,false);
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',stopDrag,false);
}
else if(window.attachEvent) {
    showCase.attachEvent('onmousedown',startDrag);
    document.body.attachEvent('onmousemove',drag);
    document.body.attachEvent('onmouseup',stopDrag);
}
function startDrag(e) {
    mouseDown = true;
}
function drag(e) {
    if(mouseDown == true) {
        for(var i=0; i < slides.length; i += 1) {
            slides[i].style.left -= e.clientX + "px";
        }
    }
}
function stopDrag(e) {
    mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

So basically what this does, is it selects all of the div elements within my showCase element. It proceeds to check whether or not my mouse is hovering over it, and if I am, it will check to see if my mouse is down, if my mouse button is down, it will check for my mouse to move left or right. This all works fine, but the issue comes into play when I try to cycle through my slides, when I try to do any form of an equation to the slides, it gives me a parse error. I think this is because when i try to reference slides[i].style.left comes out as a string. I've tried parsing it to a numeric form, and 
stripping it of characters, but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using "leftoffset" to grab the value, but no matter what I do, it either gives me an error that is "style.left is undefined", "NaN", or "parse error: declaration dropped". Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery to simplify this code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jquery but it is something that I'm currently looking into. And yes I know it isn't the correct formula, at this point I'm just trying to get it to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's this line:

```
slides[i].style.left -= e.clientX + "px";
```

If `slides[i].style.left` has a value like `10px` you can't substract an integer value. You need to remove the "px" first:

```
var leftPos = 0;
if(slides[i].style.left) {
    leftPos =  slides[i].style.left.toString().replace(/(px)/i, "");
}
slides[i].style.left = (leftPos - e.clientX) + "px";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I do believe that this would fix my issue in theory, however I'm getting the error message stating "TypeError: slides[i].style.left.replaceAll is not a function", I've already tried this several times, in slightly different ways, but I seem to get a type error regardless of how I use any regex functions.

Comment: Sorry I confuesed it with the Java replaceAll method. use `replace` instead. I updated the answer. You could also use `slides[i].style.left.toString().replace(...)` to convert it to a string.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help, this fixed the core issue I was having, which was changing the value of the left position. I'll have to figure out why its setting the value to -55,000 - -60,000. But that should be easy, now that I can change the values around.

Comment: So could you please accept the answer in order to tell future users that this answer was correct. Thank you :)